# Maximo Anywhere - Workorder Specifications Offline

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I've spoke to IBM and they say this is working as designed so my question is how can i make it so that it automatically downloads the workorder specifications on the work list screen.

Currently if offline and you go into a workorder detail, the specifications are not visible. Only those you have viewed previously as they will be cached locally onto the device

My thoughts was just adding it as a required resource on the work list UI on the app.xml but that didn't seem the work.

Sort of need to call the same function as "Download Work List" but only for specifications

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to roll your own code for this. We did it, but with a fair amount of custom code.

Answer (score 0):

IV98368: WHERE SPECIFICATIONS AREN'T BEING SYNCHRONIZED IN PROPER ORDER
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV98368

Comments
defect 282032 investigated problem, found configuration to change.  information passed to customer to close PMR.  APAR not
valid.